# Sql Server - pass array to procedure

Tags: sql-server

I need to pass set of int to sql procedure.

```
alter PROC PrCustomerServicesUpd(
                                     @CustomerId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
                                     @ServicesIdXml NVARCHAR(1000),
                                     @ServicesIdCount INT =1
)
AS 
DECLARE @XmlDocHanle INT
EXEC sp_Xml_PrepareDocument @XmlDocHanle OUTPUT, @ServicesIdXml

SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@XmlDocHanle, '/ROOT/Services/ServicesId',@ServicesIdCount)
WITH (ServiceId INT)


EXEC sp_Xml_RemoveDocument @XmlDocHanle 



go
PrCustomerServicesUpd '443c293e-fc78-4562-97f8-ee1f2b54f813'
,'<Services><ServiceId>12</ServiceId><ServiceId>156</ServiceId></Services>',22
```

This script returns one empty field  named 'ServiceId' instead of 2 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is SQL Server 2000 (otherwise there is **no** sane reason to use OPENXML), you need to get the `text()` within the node, otherwise it tries to find the attribute "ServiceId" within the node "ServiceId".  Also your parameter XML is completely out of sync with what the proc expects.

```
alter PROC PrCustomerServicesUpd(
                                     @CustomerId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
                                     @ServicesIdXml NVARCHAR(1000),
                                     @ServicesIdCount INT =1
)
AS 
DECLARE @XmlDocHanle INT
EXEC sp_Xml_PrepareDocument @XmlDocHanle OUTPUT, @ServicesIdXml

SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@XmlDocHanle, '/ROOT/Services/ServicesId',@ServicesIdCount)
WITH (ServiceId INT 'text()')


EXEC sp_Xml_RemoveDocument @XmlDocHanle 
GO

PrCustomerServicesUpd '443c293e-fc78-4562-97f8-ee1f2b54f813'
,'<ROOT><Services><ServicesId>12</ServicesId><ServicesId>156</ServicesId></Services></ROOT>',3
```

Using the XML data type

```
alter PROC PrCustomerServicesUpd
 @CustomerId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
 @ServicesIdXml xml,
 @ServicesIdCount INT =1
AS
select service.id.value('.','int')
from @ServicesIdXml.nodes('/ROOT/Services/ServicesId') service(id)
GO
```

Comment: It works properly. What do you recommend to use for sql server 2008 r2 instead of openxml ?

Comment: @Alex / Please see xml data type usage in the answer

Comment: Do you mean 'text()'? What does it mean?

Comment: @alex / No I mean the 2nd code block. That's the proper, better way to do it in 2008 R2.

Comment: Good! I   have not known about it!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass set of int in varchar(1000) with comma separator

so int value passing as "1223,12,254,5545,8787,8787,787,78,45475,45,45"

And in store procedure you can get one by one id with fnSplit function (Tabular).

```
ALTER function [dbo].[fnSplit](
 @String nvarchar (4000),
 @Delimiter nvarchar (10)
 )
returns @ValueTable table ([Value] nvarchar(4000))
begin
 declare @NextString nvarchar(4000)
 declare @Pos int
 declare @NextPos int
 declare @CommaCheck nvarchar(1)

 --Initialize
 set @NextString = ''
 set @CommaCheck = right(@String,1) 

 --Check for trailing Comma, if not exists, INSERT
 --if (@CommaCheck <> @Delimiter )
 set @String = @String + @Delimiter

 --Get position of first Comma
 set @Pos = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)
 set @NextPos = 1

 --Loop while there is still a comma in the String of levels
 while (@pos <>  0)  
 begin
  set @NextString = substring(@String,1,@Pos - 1)

  insert into @ValueTable ( [Value]) Values (@NextString)

  set @String = substring(@String,@pos +1,len(@String))

  set @NextPos = @Pos
  set @pos  = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)
 end

 return
end
```

so you can get the one by one value as

```
"Select value from dbo.fnsplit (@values,',')"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `ServiceId` and not `ServicesId`.
In addition the third parameter of OPENXML should not be @ServicesIdCount, it should be a value describing what sort of output you want.
Don't think you specify a ROOT node in your XML, so remove that

```
SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@XmlDocHanle, '/ROOT/Services/ServicesId',@ServicesIdCount)
WITH (ServiceId INT)
```

should be

```
SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@XmlDocHanle, '/Services/ServiceId', 1)
WITH (ServiceId INT)
```

Comment: That will look for ServiceId @attribute in /Services/ServiceId